# MySQL query to combine three tables with different columns and rows

Tags: mysql

```
I have below three tables in database:

users:

id  emailaddress

1   abc@sdfd.com

2   ghgf@fdgfs.com

3   hjfy@fcgfd.com


allowance_details

id  user_id allowance   date

1   1        13000      15/02/2017

2   1        10000      23/01/2016

3   2        25000      15/02/2017

4   3        15000      10/1/2017

5   3        7000       12/12/2015



bonus_details

id  user_id bonus   date

1   1        7000   15/02/2017

2   1        5000   17/01/2016

3   1        3500   23/07/2015

4   2        4500   10/1/2017

5   2        6000   16/03/2016

6   3        2500   18/6/2016

7   3        3800   24/09/2015



I want to combine above three tables and want below result:

id  emailaddress    allowance   date        bonus   date

1   abc@sdfd.com    13000       15/02/2017  7000    15/02/2017

1   abc@sdfd.com    10000       23/01/2016  5000    17/01/2016

1   abc@sdfd.com                            3500    23/07/2015

2   ghgf@fdgfs.com  25000       15/02/2017  4500    10/1/2017

2   ghgf@fdgfs.com                          6000    16/03/2016

3   hjfy@fcgfd.com  15000       10/1/2017   2500    18/6/2016

3   hjfy@fcgfd.com  7000        12/12/2015  3800    24/09/2015

3   hjfy@fcgfd.com                          4000    12/7/2014


Any one help me out what will be the correct MySQL query to fetch such result?

Below is my query:
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.emailaddress, bon.bonus, bon.date,alw.allowance,alw.date FROM users u LEFT JOIN bonus_details bon ON bon.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN allowance_details alw ON alw.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: Where is your code/query attempt ?

Comment: And please ask a specific question.

Comment: I've added query which I've used.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following :

select u.id,u.emailaddress,aw.allowance,aw.date,bd.bonus,bd.date from users u

inner join allowance_Details aw on aw.user_id = u.id

inner join bonus_details bd on bd.user_id = u.id

Comment: Can you please tell what result you getting after run this. You can use Left join rather than inner as well or try left outer join